# PHP form to update MYSQL Row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP form that updates a MySQL database. I want to add credits to the current credits in the row. Basic math

Current Credits 50 add another 50 credits = 100

This is my current string (EDITED)

```
    $sql = sprintf("UPDATE h_clients ". "SET credits = $credits + '%s'" . "WHERE id = $id",

Currently this works but it doesn't add the new credits with the current credits in DB 

Here is the full code:

$sql = sprintf("UPDATE h_clients ". "SET credits = $credits + '%s'" . "WHERE id = $id",

 mysql_real_escape_string($credit),
               mysql_real_escape_string($id));

            if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
                $insertSuccessful = true;
            } else {
                echo $sql;
                echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);
                echo "mysql err no : " . mysql_errno($con);
            }
    }

    }

    return $insertSuccessful;
```

Comment: try $sql = sprintf("UPDATE h_clients ". "SET credits = credits + '%s'" . "WHERE id = $id",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have wrong column name in assign credits

```
"UPDATE h_clients SET credits = credits +  $credits  WHERE id = $id",
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, think to many "" in my code and calling the credits currently in the DB instead of the %S i tried

Comment: Well if work .. and my answer is right please mark it as accepted ..

Answer (score 1):

If you are just adding to the value that's stored in the database, you should be able to do this:

```
$sql = sprintf("UPDATE h_clients SET credits = credits + $credits WHERE id = $id",

 mysql_real_escape_string($credit),
            mysql_real_escape_string($id));
```

Please clarify if this is not what you intended.